# One-to-many relationship using same SQL table

Tags: sql, database-design, one-to-many

I'm in the process of designing my database and one of the Tables (Tasks), needs to be able to have a one-to-many relationship with itself. This is because a task can have a number of sub-tasks that have the same data (much like a question and answer on SO).

I'm just a little confused, due to my not very strong SQL, as to how to make a one-to-many on the same table.

Currently I have these rows:

> TaskId (uniqueidentifier)
>   aspnet_OwnerUserId (uniqueidentifier)
>   Title (nvarchar(50)) 
>   Description (nvarchar(MAX))
>   StartDate (smalldatetime)
>   DueDate (smalldatetime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I am not very sure what you are going to achieve, but depending on what you've given as the table fields, I think a one-to-many relationship with the table itself is more appropriate.

```
TaskId (integer *Primary Key)
Ref_Id (integer *Foreign Key references to TaskId above)
ASPNet_OwnerUserId (integer)
Title (varchar/text)
StartDate (Date/Timestamp)
DueDate (Date/Timestamp)
```

If you want a subtask to have multiple parent tasks, then please forget what I have said.  That said, one or more answers can be made to a certain question, but not the other way around.

EDIT:
I would suppose you are going to have another table "aspnet_OwnerUser" which holds some user info.  Please take a look of the follow SQL if that's the case.  Otherwise, forget it.  ;)

```
CREATE TABLE `aspnet_OwnerUser`
(
    `id` SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    , `name` VARCHAR(128)
    -- further detail follows
);

CREATE TABLE `task`
(
    `id` SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    , `ref_id` INTEGER
        CONSTRAINT REFERENCES `task`(`id`)
    , `aspnet_OwnerUserId` INTEGER
        CONSTRAINT REFERENCES `aspnet_OwnerUser`(`id`)
    , `title` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
    , `startdate` TIMESTAMP
    , `duedate` TIMESTAMP
);
```

p.s. the above SQL is written for PostgreSQL, for other DBMS, please feel free to alter it.

Comment: Yeah, it appears I'm more of a moron that it first appeared and a one-to-many is exactly what I was thinking. I just couldn't seem to make by brain translate that. Updating question.

Comment: Thanks for putting my brain back on the straight and narrow. /bows

Answer (score 3):

The intersection (junction) table is coded pretty much as you would expect, only with two foreign keys pointing at the same table.

```
create table task_subtasks
 ( master_id number not null
   , sub_id number not null
   , constraint task_subtask_pk primary key (master_id, sub_id)
    , constraint task_subtask_master_fk foreign key (master_id)
         references tasks (taskid)
    , constraint task_subtask_sub_fk foreign key (sub_id)
         references tasks (taskid)
    )
/
```

**edit**

Having typed that up, I would like to interrogate your data model.  I can see that a task can own many sub-tasks, but I am not sure how a sub-task can belong to many master tasks.  Are you sure you don't really want a one-to-many relationship?

**edit 2**

While I was writing that edit I see you edited your question to answer that point.

```
create table tasks (
TaskId number not null
, aspnet_OwnerUserId number not null
, subTaskId number
, Title (nvarchar(50))
, Description (nvarchar(MAX))
, StartDate (smalldatetime)
, DueDate (smalldatetime)
, constraint task_pk primary key (taskid)
, constraint sub_task_fk foreign key (subtaskid)
    references tasks (taskid)
)
/
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for a many-to-many. Thanks to shinkou, I have been corrected.

Comment: @Alastair Pitts - On this site it's not always easy to tell whether the given data model is the real target or just a simplified test case.

Answer (score 2):

If your analogy is like a question and answer on SO then this is not a many-to-many relationship, it is a one-to-many relationship.  One question may have several answers, but an answer belongs to one and only one question.  The simplest way to map this is:

**Table - Tasks**

```
TaskID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
ParentTaskID uniqueidentifier NULL,
(other fields)
```

Then create a self-referencing foreign key constraint from `ParentTaskID` to `TaskID`.

Let's say that for some reason you really do need a M:M mapping.  That has to be done using a mapping table; a self-refeferencing M:M isn't really any different from a M:M involving two tables:

**Table - Tasks**

```
TaskID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
(other fields)
```

**Table - SubTasks**

```
TaskID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
SubTaskID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
```

Place a foreign key constraint on both `TaskID` and `SubTaskID` in the `SubTasks` table that references the `Tasks (TaskID)` column.  The only difference between this and any other M:M relationship is that both foreign key constraints point to the same table (and on some DBMSes, you won't be able to cascade both of them).

Comment: Good answer for both my original issue and the updated corrected issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you could do this as a many-to-many but really its more like a [nested set](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).